# multiple users same desktop

Tags: cinnamon

I have my desktop set up how I like it for my admin (root) user (Cinnamon)

I want to create a non-admin account, but keep the same desktop setup as the root.

How to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this an official distro of Ubuntu?That is, did you install the Cinnamon DE yourself?

Comment: Define "same desktop setup".

Comment: I installed Ubuntu, then added Cinnanmon myself.

Comment: "same desktop setup" to me means having the same desktop look as the root user has, but when logging in as just a regular non-root user.

Comment: Ubuntu dosen't have a root user

Comment: The admin account

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you mean the account with sudo access when you say root.

Its pretty simple where you want to copy userone's account to usertwo - create a new account (usertwo), copy over the contents of /home/userone to /home/usertwo (with sudo cp, to handle permissions issues), then `sudo chown -R  usertwo /home/usertwo` to give ownership of the directory to the new user.

If you want *all* users to have the same initial account setup, I believe setting `/etc/skel` appropriately will do the trick

Comment: JG - yes, you are correct. I tried to copy the files over, but it won't allow me to paste them over.

Comment: did you use sudo to copy over?

Comment: No. I don't know how.

Comment: If I need to enter the admin PW to use SUDO, then I'm not logged in as admin?

Comment: not really, it just means you're in the sudoers account and temporarily got your priviledges bumped up

Comment: Thanks, I'm understanding it better now, I think. In reading about how Ubuntu was designed, I see that the initial account that was created during install is this default account - which, when the PW for sudo is entered, temporary becomes the Admin for a short time. When this sudo session expires, the account goes back to a regular (default) user status. Thus, this account is more secure, as it's not having admin privileges all the time. Is this correct? If this is the case, then I have no need to make another account and have it look like the default account, I can  use the default account.